# log4j: what happen when size of log file is close to limit?

Tags: log4j, log4j2, rollingfileappender

Assume that the size limit is 10M and the current size of log is 9M.
When I use `logger.info()` to append a string, with 2M size
the log will be renamed `log.1` and create a new log file.

I want to know if `log4j` is about to split such string, how to prevent it from splitting and moving the entire string to the current log file?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be splited, log.1 would be 11M.